# Powershell test-path

Tags: powershell

Newbie help required here - I'm trying to search for the newest .csv file in F drive, then use `Test-Path` to check if that file is in the E drive. My script outputs the latest file name to screen which is correct - what I'm now trying to do is append `$_latestFile.name` to a `Test-Path` to see if this file is found in the folder in E drive.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

```
$_sourcePath = "F:\"
$_destinationPath = "E:\"
$_FileType= @("*.*csv")
$_latestFile = Get-ChildItem -Recurse ($_sourcePath) -Include ($_FileType) | Sort-Object -Property $_.CreationTime | Select-Object -Last 1 
$_latestFile.name
```

Comment: _Anywhere_ in the `E:` drive, or at the same relative location?

Comment: hi, it's something like  F:\folder\files\  and E:\Modules\   the folders won't ever change

Comment: Are you actually trying to, say, check that the latest CSV file is backed up / moved for processing to another a drive?

Comment: You should be able to do Test-Path "$_destinationPath$($_latestFile.Name)"

Comment: I think Mathias asked the right question, where in `E` drive ? Also, this might be a faster search: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_sourcePath -File -Filter *.csv`

Comment: Agreed. Also, specifying the correct value for `$destinationPath`.  Given the OP is a beginner we should probably steer toward `Join-Path` for ultimate concatenation of the file name.  Otherwise we're forced to ensure `$destinationPath` ends with "\". @Mike you're approach would have an issue if the "\" isn't present. If not using `Join-Path`, we are in beginner mode, so I'm not sure expanding strings are the best option let alone with subexpressions.  Hence, without `Join-Path` I'd use the more straightforward `+` operator to concatenate.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon is absolutely correct `-Filter` will be faster than `Include` and for that matter faster than `...\*.csv`. However, I'd question why that is forced to be an array as `-Filter` only accepts a string.

Comment: Mike's suggestion worked for me, thanks. However as Steven has highlighted a potential issue if an \ is omitted from the file path then i'll look at join-path.

Comment: i'll look at filter too, instead of using Include and file-type

Comment: thanks everyone for your input. very helpful

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to find a file in the `$_destinationPath` with the same name and modified date as the one you found on the `$_sourcePath`, you might do this:

```
$sourcePath ="F:\"
$destinationPath = "E:\"
$latestFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*.csv' -File -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property $_.LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1 
Write-Host "Latest CSV file in $sourcePath is '$($latestFile.Name)'"

$destFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationPath -Filter "$($latestFile.Name)" -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -eq $latestFile.LastWriteTime }
if ($destFile) {
    Write-Host "Copy file found at '$($destFile.FullName)'" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else {
    Write-Host "Could not find a file '$($latestFile.Name)' with the same modified date in '$destinationPath'"-ForegroundColor Red
}
```

I have changed the property `CreationTime` to `LastWriteTime` in order to get the most recently updated file. CreationTime gets changed when a file is copied to another disk..

Also (thanks Steven) I changed the variable names from `$_varname` to `$varname` to avoid confusion with PowerShell's `$_` [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#_)

Comment: FYI looks like you're missing an intended single quote in your first `Write-Host` command?

Comment: Also, seems like we should discourage the use of `$_` to lead variable names. Probably too easily conflated with with `$_` or`$_. ...` in other contexts.

Comment: @Steven Correct on both counts ! I have updates the variable names and inserted the missing `'`

Comment: thanks so much, Theo. Will look to doing this asap too

Comment: @Theo, Glad I could contribute.